# python adding key value pair to dict, value is missing and result is a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

maybe it's to late and I am missing something stupid.

I am trying to add a key, value pair to a dict within a loop:

```
    self.categories = {}
    cat = 0
    for value in self.limits:
        self.categories['category {0:02d}'.format(cat)] = '{0:03d} to {1:03d}'.format(value[0], value[1])
        cat += 1       
    print(sorted(self.categories))
```

I would expect the following:

```
{'category 01': '000 to 005', 'category 03': '020 to 040', 'category 00': '000 to 000', 'category 02': '005 to 020'}
```

But I am getting this as result, that's really confusing...

```
['category 00', 'category 01', 'category 02', 'category 03']
```

Can someone explain this?
Thank you!

Comment: See the [documentation for `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted): "Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable."

Comment: You're trying to sort a dictionary which is unordered. What you're getting is a sorted list of keys. It's not clear to me how your expected output is sorted, so it seems an unnecessary call?

Comment: That's how make someone feel dump :D Thank you.